# tinc: command not found after installing Tinc VPN

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, vpn, tinc

I installed and configured TINC VPN on server (Ubuntu 22.04 and two laptops) but when I try to use tinc control command I get "command not found".

All this happened when I tried to configure tinc on y Android phone via invitation link.

```
 tinc -n <netname> invite [nodename]
```

But I got the following

```
Command 'tinc' not found, did you mean:
  command 'tini' from deb tini (0.19.0-1)
  command 'tic' from deb ncurses-bin (6.3-2ubuntu0.1)
  command 'tincd' from deb tinc (1.0.36-2build1)
  command 'tint' from deb tint (0.07)
  command 'tipc' from deb iproute2 (5.15.0-1ubuntu2)
  command 'inc' from deb mailutils-mh (1:3.14-1)
  command 'inc' from deb mmh (0.4-4)
  command 'inc' from deb nmh (1.7.1-11)
  command 'tin' from deb tin (1:2.6.2~20220129-1)
  command 'tidc' from deb moonshot-trust-router (3.5.4+1ubuntu1)
  command 'minc' from deb mblaze (1.1-1)
  command 'tina' from deb tina (0.1.12-4)
Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

How come the tinc got installed and the tinc control command is missing?

UPD: tinc was installed using this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-tinc-and-set-up-a-basic-vpn-on-ubuntu-18-04

UPD [RESOLVED]: tinc command is a part of 1.1, which is in pre-release state

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add details how exactly you installed `tinc`.

Comment: The tutorial might contain commands or configuration files that must be adjusted to your environment, and you might have made mistakes, you should show the commands/files you actually used on your systems. This question is not about programming but about configuring your system. It might better fit on askubuntu.com

Comment: Nowhere in those instructions does it ever mention the command is called `tinc`. It mentions that the command is called `tincd`. In the package provided by ubuntu, the binary is installed in `/usr/sbin/tincd`

Comment: I assume you ran `sudo apt install tinc`. This package contains an executable program `tincd`, but not `tinc`. The Ubuntu package search does not find an executable program of this name. The Tutorial does not mention such a command. I only found a reference to this command in a guide from 2016 with a locally built tinc-1.1pre15 https://nwgat.ninja/quick-easy-tinc-1-1-2/ and a guide that uses a different package source https://florianjensen.com/2022/08/18/tinc-mesh-vpn-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts/ Maybe the command `tinc` was added in a newer version that is not yet available as an official package.

Comment: omg, you're right. It seems the command is in version 1.1 which is in pre-release atm. Apologies for the question, after a couple of hard days I missed such a simple thing. Thanks a lot for the clear view!